# React Typescript - Can't pass fetch response to child component [hooks, functionalComponent]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have been trying to pass the `response` object from making a `fetch` request to a child component of a functional component. The simplified code to do this in the parent component is as follows:

```
 <Datatable data={response} />
```

The idea is then inside the child component to map over all the statusCode and statusText entries for each request made by the Fecth API and create a new row in a table. Should be easy right?

However, I can't understand the error message I'm getting `Type 'RequestProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestProps[]'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestProps[]'`. For context I have defined two `types` one to have the type for a response and then a type for an array of these types as follows:

```
type RequestProps = {
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
}

type Props = {
  data: RequestProps[]; 
}
```

I have a sandbox environment [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/3mzjr7q) for testing.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for checking it out for me but there is an error is line 33  <Datatable data={response} /> in the NetworkDiagnostics component that I'm struggling to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial value is `RequestProps[] | undefined`, to fix it add a specific initial type (a `RequestProps[]` type only):

```
// response type is `RequestProps[] | undefined`
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<RequestProps[]>();

// Add an initial value (an empty array `[]`)
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<RequestProps[]>([]);
```

[image: Edit blue-sound-d0h7o]

Comment: Interesting! I thought defining the type of the state was enough...apparently not! Thanks for the help and I accepted your answer!